# How to detect if equals() and hashCode() have gotten out of sync with a class's fields?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I have a codebase where in almost every case, a class that implements `equals` and `hashCode` should include comparisons and hashes of every field the class contains. For instance, the default `equals` and `hashCode` methods that an IDE will auto-generate are appropriate. Creating these methods is easy, but maintaining them over time is hard. Is there an automated tool that can analyze a codebase and produce a list of classes whose `equals` and `hashCode` methods are not in sync with their fields?

In the best case, it would have each of the following features, but a tool that just does #1 is already useful:

1. List `classes` that have `equals` and `hashCode` implementations that use a different set of fields from each other or from the fields defined on the class.
2. Allow a way to specify that certain fields on a class are intentionally excluded from `equals`/`hashCode`, and should therefore *not* appear in `equals`/`hashCode`.
3. Also list classes that have a mismatch between their fields and their `equals`/`hashCode` due to inheritance. These are classes that define fields and that either

   - override equals and hashCode from a `superclass` but fail to include `super.equals`/`super.hashCode` in the overrides,
   - override `equals`/`hashCode` and call super, but the `superclass` defines fields and does not override its own `equals` and `hashCode`, or
   - inherit a custom `equals` and `hashCode` from a `superclass` without overriding it.

Comment: Sorry, asking for tool recommendations is off-topic. See the [help] and [ask].

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand the underlying reasoning here: hashCode and equals are not required to rely on every single object field. Mandating that this be the case is your choice, not an inherent quality of java code? Why would you put this restriction in place? And how would you even guarantee that code that _does_ use every field, does so meaningfully?

Comment: @m.antkowicz Which part of Jim's comment is nasty? It is a very nice comment, simply informing OP of the site rules.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans in practice using all the fields is frequently the correct behavior, and the cost of being wrong can be high and hard to discover. If a developer intentionally leaves out certain fields, they can annotate this at low cost. What I've described is a static analysis that makes it possible to avoid the most likely accidents. I agree that it remains possible to non-meaningfully use a field, but that's a much rarer failure mode. A solution to 99% of the problem is more useful than no solution.

Comment: And @JimGarrison and others - apologies for asking this in the wrong forum. I'll keep this in mind going forward. Thanks to those who have written back anyway.

Comment: @m.antkowicz The *"Is there an automated tool ..."* in the question *is* an ask for a tool recommendation, so teaching a relatively new user (500 rep) of SO about some of the rules of the site is *helpful*, not nasty and useless. Or don't you think it's helpful to guide users to [how to ask better questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so they are more likely to get good useful answers? I do. --- Also, it was done as a *comment*, not as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an automated tool that can analyze a codebase and produce a list of classes whose equals and hashCode methods are not in sync with their fields

You can use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) - java library that is automatically genereting boiler plate code for your java classes. You are adding this as dependency, putting [special annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) to your class and that's all - with every change it will regenerate proper methods for you

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class MyComplicatedClass {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This looks useful. From Lombok's documentation:
Any class definition may be annotated with EqualsAndHashCode to let lombok generate implementations of the equals(Object other) and hashCode() methods. By default, it'll use all non-static, non-transient fields, but you can modify which fields are used (and even specify that the output of various methods is to be used) by marking type members with EqualsAndHashCode.Include or EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude. Alternatively, you can specify exactly which fields or methods you wish to be used by marking them with EqualsAndHashCode.Include...